# Tunneling Proxies through PHP

Tags: php, proxy

Is it possible to have this setup:

```
[browser] -> [proxy_1 2.2.2.2:800x (PHP_SCRIPT)] -> [proxy_2 1.1.1.x:8080 (HTTP)] -> [remote server]
```

I have many proxies like this:

```
1.1.1.1:8080
1.1.1.2:8080
1.1.1.3:8080
```

I would like the PHP script to accept incoming connection, and forward it to my real proxies, so that I could simply give out my **masked** proxies:

```
2.2.2.2:8080
2.2.2.2:8081
2.2.2.2:8082
```

Is this possible with PHP sockets? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to make sure that your proxy1 will forward the connections to proxy2, and only proxy2 will forward directly the connections. If you want to use PHP sockets you will need to parse HTTP headers and process the entire connection. You could use curl library for this.

Here is a project which uses the proxy concept with curl:
https://github.com/jenssegers/php-proxy

Comment: How to use php-proxy ? document ?
Where to setup & steps

Comment: @user1635700 the updated exemples are available in the project page in the link above.

Comment: little depends on zend, looking without zend depends

Comment: @user1635700 you could take a look into https://github.com/Athlon1600/php-proxy, but it depends on Symfony. What exactly are you trying to achieve?